# Change column heading of the table

Tags: vaadin

i am trying to learn more about the sqlcontainer and was able to create a read only table with the data from a sql server.  I've used the freeformquery like "select * from table1". Now i am trying to change the column headings of the table.  What i've done was to set the sqlcontainer by using the freeformquery and set the table's datasource to that sqlcontainer.

i see from the api that there is a setColumnHeader method that takes the propertyId and a string.  How do i get the propertyid of the first column or second column?

Comment: Should be the name (Case sensitive) of the fiels in your sql table

Answer (score 2):

```
Table.setColumnHeader()
```

is what you are looking for: propertyId is in fact the name of the field in your container. So if you have

```
SELECT id, name FROM person
```

you can do

```
table.setColumnHeader("id", "Table key");
table.setColumnHeader("Name", "Person's name");
```

unfortunately there's no positional setting directly but you could, if needed, do something like

```
List<Object> ids = Arrays.asList(categorieTable.getItemIds().toArray());
categorieTable.setColumnHeader(ids.get(0), "Table key");
categorieTable.setColumnHeader(ids.get(1), "Person's name");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case table propertyIds are column names in your database. You can obtain table propertyIds using method table.getContainerPropertyIds()

Given database table with two columns "id" and "name" you can change "id" header to "Santa Claus Id" using following code (you don't have to iterate, I just wanted to show how can you obtain propertyIds):

```
        Collection<?> columnIds = table.getContainerPropertyIds();
        for(Object propertyId : columnIds)
        {
            if(propertyId.equals("id"))
            {
                table.setColumnHeader(propertyId, "Santa Claus Id");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code example equals to table.setColumnHeader("id", "Santa Claus Id");